# Logitech M720 mouse disconnects from Unifying USB Receiver randomly on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: 20.04, usb, logitech

Previously I was using Logitech M720 mouse in my laptop but connected via bluetooth, it worked fine in Ubuntu 18.04. Now I got a new PC and installed Ubuntu 20.04.3, since that PC does not includes bluetooth I tried using the Unifying USB Receiver that comes with the mouse, but the mouse disconnects randomly from it and re-connects right after. What might be causing this? I tried installing [logiops](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops) but it did not worked.

Linux Kernel is `5.11.0-38-generic`.

I have a dualboot with Windows 10 and there those disconnections don't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I connected the unifying receiver to USB 3.0 port, switching to USB 2.0 port solved the problem. I don't think it was some kind of interference because both ports are on same side of chassis (back). Looks like it does not works well in USB 3.0 ports.